# @Tag OpenAPI annotation on Resource producer method

Tags: openapi, quarkus, microprofile, smallrye

I am using Quarkus 3.2 with quarkus-smallrye-openapi extension.
I would like to place `@Tag` annotations from Microprofile OpenAPI on JAX-RS resource producer methods:

```java
@Path("/search")
public class SearchResource {

  @Path("profile1")
  @Tag(name="Profile 1 Resource", description="Search Profile 1")
  public SearchResource searchProfile1() {
    return new SearchResource(profile1Config);
  }

  @Path("profile2")
  @Tag(name="Profile 2 Resource", description="Search Profile 2")
  public SearchResource searchProfile2() {
    return new SearchResource(profile2Config);
  }
```

`SearchResource` is JAX-RS resource class containing several operations.

The generated OpenAPI contracts contains:

```yaml
paths:
  /search/profile1/summary:
    get:
      tags:
      - Search Resource
  /search/profile1/detail:
    get:
      tags:
      - Search Resource
  /search/profile2/summary:
    get:
      tags:
      - Search Resource
  /search/profile2/detail:
    get:
      tags:
      - Search Resource
```

These `@Tag` annotations are

- OK when placed at Resource class level
- OK when placed at Operation method level (a method returning content)
- Not OK when placed at Sub-resource producer method level (a method returning a sub-resource)

Is it possible to make the last case work?

Comment: This isn't yet supported by smallrye-open-api. See also https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/discussions/1546 for further discussion. It looks like a good enhancement.